# How to use return value from one function inside another function?

Tags: python, function, return

Basically, I've created my first function and it has a return value. I want to use this return value in another function. It's Python code in PyCharm and I am beginner so I'm still new with terms and everything.

This is my first function:

```
def deposit():  # amount he wants to bet with
    while True:
        amount = input("What would you like to deposit? $")
        if amount.isdigit():
            amount = int(amount)
            if amount > 0:
                break
            else:
                print("Amount must be greater than 0$")
        else:
            print("Please enter a number")

    return amount
```

This is my second function:

```
def get_bet():
    balance = amount   **HERE IS MY PROBLEM**
    while True:
        bet = input("What would you like to bet on each line? $")
        if bet.isdigit():
            bet = int(bet)
            if bet <= balance:
                if MIN_BET <= bet <= MAX_BET and bet <= balance:
                    break
                else:
                    print(f"Bet must be between ${MIN_BET} - ${MAX_BET} ")
            else:
                print(f"Bet must be within your balance of ${balance} ")
        else:
            print("Please enter a number")

    return bet
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where do you call the first function? You'd assign the returned value to a variable, and pass that as an argument to `get_bet`. For example, you'd do: `deposited_amt = deposit()`, and then call `get_bet(deposited_amt)`, but you'd need to redefine `get_bet` to take that argument like so: `def get_bet(balance)` and get rid of the line you've marked

Answer (score 0):

Without some of the needed support information such as maximum bet and minimum bet, I used a bit of artistic license to indicate how to utilize the returned value from a function.  Following is a refactored version of your code adding in some test constant values and a "main" function to perform testing.

```
MIN_BET = 50
MAX_BET = 180

def deposit():  # amount he wants to bet with
    while True:
        amount = input("What would you like to deposit? $")
        if amount.isdigit():
            amount = int(amount)
            if amount > 0:
                break
            else:
                print("Amount must be greater than 0$")
        else:
            print("Please enter a number")

    return amount

def get_bet():
    balance = deposit() # Calling the function will populate the variable
    while True:
        bet = input("What would you like to bet on each line? $")
        if bet.isdigit():
            bet = int(bet)
            if bet <= balance:
                if MIN_BET <= bet <= MAX_BET and bet <= balance:
                    break
                else:
                    print(f"Bet must be between ${MIN_BET} - ${MAX_BET} ")
            else:
                print(f"Bet must be within your balance of ${balance} ")
        else:
            print("Please enter a number")

    return bet

def main():

    the_bet = get_bet()

    print("This is what was betted: $", the_bet)

main()
```

The key bit of refactoring was changing the statement "bet = amount" to "bet = deposit()".  The variable "amount" is a variable local the the "deposit" function.  But in this case it is the conduit of getting a deposit amount and returning the value to the betting function.  And, as you can see in the "main" function prototype, the bet amount is returned as a value to the "main" function.

Following was some test output at the terminal.

```
craig@Vera:~/Python_Programs/Bet$ python3 Bet.py 
What would you like to deposit? $600
What would you like to bet on each line? $700
Bet must be within your balance of $600 
What would you like to bet on each line? $300
Bet must be between $50 - $180 
What would you like to bet on each line? $20
Bet must be between $50 - $180 
What would you like to bet on each line? $100
This is what was betted: $ 100
```

The big take-away here would be to probably delve more into some Python tutorial literature, especially as it pertains to functions (e.g. parameters and return values).